# basics of DFT padding

Tags: dft

If $x[n]$ is length 4 sequence, with DFT $T.F\{x[n]\} = X[k]$ and $y[n]$ is a length 8 sequence obtained from $x[n]$ by padding with 4 zeros:
$$y = [x[n],0,0,0,0]$$
For $k$ even, we have $X[k] = Y[k]$

What is the DFT of $y[n]$ in terms of $X[k]$ if $k$ is odd?

Comment: Is this a homework question ?

Comment: No bro. I have downloaded few pdfs on DFT and found this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. Zero padding increases the frequency precision of the DFT by increasing the number of bins for which the DFT is computed. This is a direct result of the $N$-point DFT formula for a sequence of length $N$:
$$ X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-i2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}\tag{1}$$
One of your sequence has $N=4$, the other $N=8$ so you can't have $X[k]=Y[k]$ **whether $k$ is even or odd**.
Since this looks like a homework question, I won't give you the answer but I can give you a hint: using (1), you can write:
$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{3}x[n]e^{-i2\pi k\frac{n}{4}}$$
and since $y[n] = x[n]$ for $n = 0 \ldots 3$ and $y[n] = 0$ for $n > 3$,
$$Y[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{7}y[n]e^{-i2\pi k\frac{n}{8}} = \sum_{n=0}^{3}x[n]e^{-i2\pi k\frac{n}{8}}$$
So for $k$ even, you can see $$Y[k] = X[k/2]$$

Now, what do you get for $k$ odd?
Hint: use the shifting property of the Fourier Transform.